# Bloomberg, historical intraday government bond data

Tags: bloomberg

I would like to get 10Y and 5Y intraday historical government bond prices (best bid and ask) for different countries. I thought that I have found a solution on Bloomberg, but there are some issues.

I am using the following formula (here Sweden, 10Y is used as an example):

bid price

=BDH(“GTSEK10Y Govt”;”Open”; “01-01-2005”;”04-05-2022”; “BarTp=B”; “BarSz=1”)

ask price

=BDH(“GTSEK10Y Govt”;”Open”; “01-01-2005”;”04-05-2022”; “BarTp=A”; “BarSz=1”)

So, this gives me intraday data (for every minute) for a few months (regardless of the starting date that I use).

Problem 1:
If I do this today for different countries for 5Y, then I get the data all the way back to October 2021. But for Poland I only get data from April 2022 when using "CTPLN5Y Govt". This can happen if the country changed the 5Y benchmark bond. So, I download the Excel file from DOCS VILLIAN GO 41 where I can see when a country changed their 5Y bond. The sheet tells me that Poland did not change the bond recently, and that the current 5Y bond has the ticker AR022483 Corp. That is, "AR022483 Corp" and "CTPLN5Y Govt" should give me the same prices, but the prices are different. So, what is wrong here?

Problem 2:
I have an Excel sheet which downloads the data for different countries with the same BDH formulas that I have provided above. I have experienced a few times that the numbers for a fixed point in time can change simply if I update the file in the future. Here is an example. Last year on April 27 2021 I download the data for Russia, with the formula

=BDH(“CTRUB 10Y Govt”;”Open”; “01-01-2005”;””; “BarTp=B”; “BarSz=1”)

For the point in time "April 5 2021, 09:00" it said that the price is 104.301. Then I open the same Excel sheet one month later, on May 21 2021, without changing anything. Obviously it gives me some newer data, and deletes some of the older data. But if I look on the same point in time,"April 5 2021, 09:00" then it says that the price is 92.214.

How is that possible that a historical price on a specific point in time can change from 104.301 to 92.214? I have asked Bloomberg, but either they did not understand the problem or did not want to understand the problem - they simply referred me to some places, and I have never figured out how this can happen.

So, my problem is that because I do not understand how such problems can arise, I cannot trust the data that I get. Thus, 2 questions:

1. Do you have an idea why problems 1 and 2 above arise? Is there any logical explanation?
2. Do you know where else I could get such data, say 10 years back? I am mostly interested in Sweden (whose government bonds are traded on Nasdaq).

Thank you!

Comment: I believe 'GT' is generic, i.e. a rolling series, whereas 'CT' is only the current bond. My guess is that explains why you only get data for CTPLN5Y back to April (likely all the data for that issue) whereas the history length for GTSEK10Y is determined by BBG's limitations on intra-day data you can download.

Comment: My above comment might explain the discrepancy in the CTRUB10Y data - the data you're looking at refers to the current 10y between you first opening the sheet and reopening the sheet 1mo later.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried both CT and GT, and they always gave me exactly the same result. So, if a country changed the bond 1 month ago, then both CT and GT will give me data for 1 month back. That is, GT will NOT give more data because it automatically changes to the old bond for older dates.
And this does not explain problem 1. Poland did not change the bond recently. 
Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry - thought I might have figured it out. I don't know what to suggest beyond persevering with HDSK. Sometimes you get lucky and get put through to a product specialist who knows their stuff - though this seems to be the exception rather than the rule.